# Android GridView : Adding items to a rendered gridview

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-cursorloader

I have a `GridView` with multiple rows and each row having 2 columns.

Let's say 10 rows are being displayed and on click of a button I want to make a call to the database fetch some more items and display these items below the previously rendered items in the same `GridView`.

I am using `CursorLoader` for my DB calls.

I tried the following approach:
Swapping the grid adapter with the new fetched Cursor.
But this makes the whole `GridView` redraw itself.

Whereas I want it to just add items below it.

Any suggestions or pointers on this would be really helpful

P.S. Fetching the items in any manner is not a problem.

Comment: https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh this may be helpful.

Comment: also have a look on this https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews